# open video in fullscreen mode 

Tags: c#

how to open a video in full screen mode with C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use windows media player control and set the `FullScreenMode = True`
look here for a detailed explanation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms930695.aspx